# How do I put these properties list together?

Tags: formatting, equations

I am not how to explain this, but

I want to be able to put equations with its properites together and array does not work.

For example I want to say the set

```
$$G_k/G_j \approx H_{jk}, 1 \leq j \leq 4, 3\leq k \leq 5$$

$$W_j - W_i \aproox V_j, 2 \leq ij \leq 9$$
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "put equations with its properties together". E.g., do you wish to align the two equations on the `\approx` symbols? Please also clarify what you mean by "array does not work". What about it isn't "working"?

Comment: @Mico, I am trying to put the equations in one "box" and make the condition indices spaced out

Comment: OK. How should the equations be positioned in the 'box" (centered, left-aligned, aligned on some common element?), and what does "make the condition indices spaced out" entail?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Yo have

$$G_k/G_j \approx H_{jk}, 1 \leq j \leq 4, 3\leq k \leq 5$$ 

$$W_j - W_i \approx V_j, 2 \leq ij \leq 9$$ %\aproox corrected

You want to

\begin{align}
G_k/G_j &\approx H_{jk}, &&1 \leq j \leq 4, 3\leq k \leq 5\\
W_j - W_i &\approx V_j, &&2 \leq ij \leq 9
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

[image]

```
If you want version without equation numbers it is enough to change `align` onto `align*`.
```

Comment: Yes but the space between the condition and the equation is too close and looks awkward.

Comment: @jacobsmith See new version.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to (a) align the equations vertically on the `\approx` symbols and (b) want to set off the conditioning information off to the right, vertically aligned as well. If that's the case, you could use either an `alignat*` environment or an `array` environment to achieve this objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
G_k/G_j   &\approx H_{jk} &\qquad& 1 \leq j \leq 4,\ 3\leq k \leq 5\\
W_j - W_i &\approx V_j    && 2 \leq i,j \leq 9
\end{alignat*}

\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33} % default value: 1
\begin{array}{@{} r @{{}\approx{}} l @{\qquad} l @{}}
G_k/G_j   & H_{jk} & 1 \leq j \leq 4,\ 3\leq k \leq 5\\
W_j - W_i & V_j    & 2 \leq i,j \leq 9
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the difference between quad and just \hspace{..}

Comment: @jacobsmith - `\quad` is the same as `\hspace{1em}`. `\qquad` is the same as `\hspace{2em}`.